# Edit environment variable in registry

Tags: c#, windows, registry, clickonce, environment-variables

I want to read all environment variable from the registry and set a new value for it with c# in visual studio 2010 express.

Thus I read the subkey of local machine:

```
SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
```

and there the value of `Path`.
While reading the `Path` value:

```
reg = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(SUB_KEY_PATH, true);
```

I get an exception, that i don't have the permission for it.

Therefore I set the value in the manifest:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

But now I can’t compile my project, because ClickOnce doesn’t support it.
How can I compile a project with security level of requireAdministrator?
One solution I found is to compile it without the requireAdministrator level and afterwards I changed the value in myproject.exe.manifest. Did i see it right, that I always have to copy both files (manifest & exe-file) to another computer to run it correctly? Is it possible to put the information in the exe-file by compiling?

Comment: You need to forget about ClickOnce.

Comment: You don't disable it, you simply don't use it to deploy your product.  And use a regular installer, as created by a Setup and Deployment project.  Not available in the Express edition.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to elevate during installation then you can't use ClickOnce. That's a design choice. Your options therefore are:

1. Use a standard install package which will allow you to show the UAC elevation dialog.
2. Modify the user's `PATH` environment rather than the system-wide variable. This option is perfectly compatible with the per-user philosophy of ClickOnce.