# Environment variable for a ClickOnce application via desktop shortcut (.appref-ms)?

Tags: c#, windows, environment-variables, clickonce, shortcut-file

I have seen [Set environment variable for ClickOnce Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37703880/set-environment-variable-for-clickonce-application) but my question is slightly different.

I work on a C# ClickOnce application, that uses `public string myvar_env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MYVAR"); if (myvar_env == "skip_stage_01") ...`. When the application is "published", I get a setup.exe which I can run as an installer - and ultimately, it ends by placing MyApp.appref-ms shortcut on the desktop.

If browsed in Windows 10 via right-click/Properties, this shortcut does not contain the actual path to the .exe; otherwise [ClickOnce .appref-ms more than a link to .application file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281173/clickonce-appref-ms-more-than-a-link-to-application-file) notes:

> If you open the appref-ms file in a text editor you'll see it contains
> the Url for the application, culture, processor architecture and key
> used to sign the application, so yes, it's just a link.
>
> The difference between those "Application Reference" files and
> shortcuts (.lnk) is that the application reference points to the
> original application Url and not the location of the exe on disk, when
> you run the appref-ms file the system knows how to find the copy of
> the program on the local disk and run it from there without accessing
> the Url (this is not accurate and depends on settings in the ClickOnce
> manifest, but its a close approximation).

Right, so I can search and eventually find the actual MyApp.exe; if I open cmd.exe at the folder location of MyApp.exe, then I can do this in there:

```batch
set MYVAR="skip_stage_01"
.\MyApp.exe
```

... and MyApp.exe starts fine, and takes the environment variable into account.

My question is: is this (addition of environment variable) somehow possible to do, but from the shortcut, that is the .appref-ms file? In other words, can I open the .appref-ms file as a text file, and add some sort of an invocation there equivalent to cmd.exe/batch "`set MYVAR="skip_stage_01"`", so then when I double-click the shortcut, the application starts and sees this environment variable as being set to the given value?